# Discord.py error: no attrbute named client

Tags: python

I am new to coding and I made a discord bot by copy-pasting the code on freecodecamp.
When I ran the program, it gave me this message:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\polly\Desktop\HACK\Discord Bot\Python\bot.py", line 4, in 
client = discord.Client()
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Client'*

Here is my original code:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: "I am new to coding and I made a discord bot by copy-pasting the code" **Do not do this.** If you are new to coding, then you need to learn how coding works. A discord bot is more complex than what you can expect to handle right now, and copying and pasting code does not teach you anything.

Comment: Are you sure that you installed the correct package of [`discord.py`](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/)?

Comment: When you are ready for this task, among many other skills, you will know without needing to be told to try things like, for example, copying and pasting `AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Client'` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=AttributeError%3A+module+%27discord%27+has+no+attribute+%27Client%27), or how to check what the contents of the imported module actually are, or how to locate and read relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to check your installing portion
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#installing

also, through my research, I found this link which is very similar to your code but with a slight difference, and I ran it through my visual code without any problems
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have installed the wrong package, you must install `discord.py` (by running `pip install discord.py` or `pip3 install discord.py` if on Linux), you installed `discord` which is an outdated mirror of `discord.py`. To fix this, run:

- `pip(3) uninstall discord` to remove the old one
- `pip(3) install discord.py` to install the new one